# How to use special characters in password for mule endpoint

Tags: encoding, mule, password-protection

Im trying to access an outbound-endpoint sending login password for it, but the password have a # character, so ive tryed encode it to %23 and even so im getting an error message...
How can i can send it?

My code:

```
<http:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" path="path/path" port="8080" user="username" password="paswd%23" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
```

And the error is:

```
Invalid uri 'http://username:paswd#@localhost:8080/path/path
```

Mule version 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double encode the password:

```
password="paswd%2523"
```

Comment: lol it worked, %2523 double encode the # from password and it actually work, that was funny... Ty again David!

Comment: `No%2520problem%2520Jader%2520%253A)` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Need to encode. As @daviddessot mentioned. That's right.
As a extention:
Feel free to use: http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Major chars:

- ! - **%21**
- $ - **%24**
- % - **%25**
- @ - **%40**

Comment: Can you please let me know why this is not working even after changing * to %2A      . details :                                             Port: 31415
(Protocol: SFTP)
Username: TFS-LP0160

Comment: i was trying to write to root directory of sftp for which path should be '///' and i was using '/'